# how to have fixed with list or anchor element in html?

Tags: html, css

I have website with list and anchor links.

I want to have the anchor length is fixed so that it will not come to next line.

When I move the mouse over,the remaining text should be displayed and when the over leave out of the link, it should be again set back to normal one line.

I want the one like the green color.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

http://jsbin.com/etete3/2

Tested in FF 3.6 IE 8 and 7

html

```
<a href="#" id="hello">Hello World, how are you, where is peace</a>

<a href="#" id="hello2">Hello World, how are you, where is peace</a>
```

css

```
a {background:yellow;width:150px;display:block;height:20px;overflow:hidden}

a:hover {background:pink;display:block;overflow:visible;height:auto;}
```

I just added color for example. you can give your styling

Answer (score 0):

How about using the `height` attribute? Set a fixed height for the element, then make the height become `auto` on hover.

Answer (score 0):

Only setting a fixed height and making that height as 'auto' on hover will not work in all the cases, that will create text overlapping issues in some cases. We need to set the 'overflow' attribute also to 'hidden'.